# Unwanted margins in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

An Image in my `ScrollView` has margins on top and bottom that I didn't set in the layout. Where can they come from?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="25dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:id="@+id/InfoText"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/InfoImage"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/InfoImageText" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/InfoImageSource"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The margin you see in the screenshot is also on top of the image
[image: Screenshot of image margin]

Comment: Check the height of the image

Comment: the image is as high as you see it, so it has no transparent stripes on top and bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is being scaled and resized to fit your layout properly.

You can change this how you like, using the [`android:scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) attribute in your layout.

For example...

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/InfoImage"/>
```